# Stored procedure throws "Error converting data type"

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

I have been failing at this for days. Please any help is appreciated.

Stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_APP_Create_Universal_Charge_Numbers] 
    @serviceID          int,
    @Parent             varchar(128),
    @level1             varchar(128),
    @level2             varchar(128),
    @level3             varchar(128),
    @level4             varchar(128),
    @ChargeCodes        varchar(500) OUTPUT,
    @Status             int OUTPUT,
    @StatusDescription  varchar(512) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Declare some variables
    DECLARE @temp_ChargeCodes varchar(500)

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    -- SELECT @ChargeCodes = 'TBD,100'
-- Wrap the entire procedure in a try..catch to trap and record errors
BEGIN TRY
    -- Set the Status value to 0
    SELECT @Status = 0
    SELECT @StatusDescription = ''

    -- Trim leading and trailing spaces from passed parameters
    SELECT @parent = LTRIM(RTRIM(@parent))
    SELECT @level1 = LTRIM(RTRIM(@level1))
    SELECT @level2 = LTRIM(RTRIM(@level2))
    SELECT @level3 = LTRIM(RTRIM(@level3))
    SELECT @level4 = LTRIM(RTRIM(@level4))

    -- Embed the calls for each service
    IF @serviceID = 0
    BEGIN          -- Dummy section
        SELECT @temp_ChargeCodes = '000'
    END            -- Dummy section
    ELSE IF @serviceID = 2
    BEGIN          -- Create Universal Record for SQL Database
        EXEC sp_SQL_Create_Universal_Charge_Numbers @serviceID, @parent, @level1, @level2, @ChargeCodes, 1, @status = @status output, @StatusDescription = @StatusDescription output    
    END            -- Create Universal Record for SQL Database
    ELSE IF @serviceID = 14
    BEGIN          -- Create Universal Record for File Shares
        EXEC sp_DISKLEASE_Create_Universal_Charge_Numbers @serviceID, @parent, @level1, @level2, @level3, @level4, @ChargeCodes, 1, @status = @status output, @StatusDescription = @StatusDescription output    
    END            -- Create Universal Record for File Shares
    ELSE IF @serviceID = 17
    BEGIN          -- Create Universal Record for Azure
        EXEC sp_AZURE_Create_RG_Universal_Charge_Numbers @serviceID, @parent, @level1, @level2, @ChargeCodes, 1, @status = @status output, @StatusDescription = @StatusDescription output   
    END            -- Create Universal Record for Azure
    ELSE IF @serviceID = 20
    BEGIN          -- Create Universal Record for AKS
        EXEC sp_AKS_Create_Universal_Charge_Numbers @serviceID, @parent, @level1, @level2, @level3, @ChargeCodes, 1, @status = @status output, @StatusDescription = @StatusDescription output
    END           -- Create Universal Record for AKS
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Set the output status and error description
    SELECT @Status = -1
    SELECT @StatusDescription = 'A SQL ERROR occurred.  USERNAME:'+SUSER_SNAME()+' Error #:'+CONVERT(varchar,ERROR_NUMBER())+' State:'+CONVERT(varchar,ERROR_STATE())+' Severity:'+CONVERT(varchar,ERROR_SEVERITY())+' Line:'+CONVERT(varchar,ERROR_LINE())+' Procedure:'+ERROR_PROCEDURE()+ ' MSG:'+ERROR_MESSAGE()
    SELECT @temp_ChargeCodes = 'UNKNOWN,100'
END CATCH
END
```

Here is how I am calling it with my powershell script. I believe the initial connection is being made and that its possible the error is coming from sql side.

```
cls

[string]$newserver = "AAAAAA"
[string]$newsharename = "gts-opsdev_test"
[string]$billingsharename = "$newserver\$newsharename"
[string]$location = "RTPNFIL02_VOL13"
[string]$approver1 = "Richard Clark"
[string]$chargecode = "1234.456.664, 100"


$Server = "rtpwlownsql05\privdev"
$Database = "ITSBilling"

$SqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server = $Server; Database = $Database; Integrated Security = True;")
$SqlConn.Open()

$cmd = $SqlConn.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandType = 'StoredProcedure'
$cmd.CommandText = 'sp_APP_Create_Universal_Charge_Numbers'

$p0 = $cmd.Parameters.Add('@serviceID',[int])
$p0.ParameterDirection.Input
$p0.Value = 14

$p1 = $cmd.Parameters.Add('@parent',[string])
$p1.ParameterDirection.Input
$p1.Value = $newserver

$p2 = $cmd.Parameters.Add('@level1',[string])
$p2.ParameterDirection.Input
$p2.Value = $billingsharename

$p3 = $cmd.Parameters.Add('@level2',[string])
$p3.ParameterDirection.Input
$p3.Value = $location

$p4 = $cmd.Parameters.Add('@level3',[string])
$p4.ParameterDirection.Input
$p4.Value = $billingsharename

$p5 = $cmd.Parameters.Add('@level4',[string])
$p5.ParameterDirection.Input
$p5.Value = $approver1

$p6 = $cmd.Parameters.Add('@ChargeCodes',[string])
$p6.ParameterDirection.Input
$p6.Value = $chargecode

$p7 = $cmd.Parameters.Add('@Status',[int])
$p7.ParameterDirection.Output
$p7.Value = "@Status OUTPUT"

$p8 = $cmd.Parameters.Add('@StatusDescription',[string])
$p8.ParameterDirection.Output
$p8.Value = "@StatusDescription OUTPUT"

$results = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

$SqlConn.Close()
$results
```

Here is the output I am getting when running. I expect it to return a 0 depending on success or a error message if not successful.

```
Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Error converting data type nvarchar to int."
At line:57 char:1
+ $results = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks @Larnu I just mainly wanted to make sure my syntax was correct as this is the first time working with sp.

Comment: @Larnu Also I'm pretty sure line 57 is the line number in the application code, not the T-SQL line number passed back from SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu Oh yeah, I wasn't meaning to discount your comment, I just didn't want the op to spend too much time focusing on line 57 of the procedure, that's all.

Comment: Aside... `CONVERT(varchar,ERROR_NUMBER())` and friends is bad practice. Get into the habit of providing a length specifier to the `varchar` type, e.g.: `varchar(10)`, to avoid surprises down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the syntax.

Works like a charm coded as

```
$SqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server = $Server; Database = $Database; Integrated Security = True;")
$SqlConn.Open()

$cmd = $SqlConn.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
$cmd.CommandText = "sp_APP_Create_Universal_Charge_Numbers"

$p1 = $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serviceID",$serviceid);
$p2 = $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parent",$newserver);
$p3 = $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level1",$newsharename);
$p4 = $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level2",$location);
$p5 = $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level3",$billingpath);
$p6 = $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level4",$approver1);
$p7 = $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChargeCodes",$billingchargecode);

$p8 = $cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status",[system.data.SqlDbType]::Int) | out-Null
$p8 = $cmd.Parameters['@Status'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Output

$p9 = $cmd.Parameters.Add("@StatusDescription",[system.data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 100) | out-Null
$p9 = $cmd.Parameters['@StatusDescription'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Output

$results = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).